# python dataframe to dictionary, key value issue

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, key-value

I am creating a dataframe and then converting to a dictionary as below

```
data = {'ID': [1,2,3,4,5],
       'A':['1','2','1','3','2'],
       'B':[4,6,8,2,4]}
frame = pd.DataFrame(data)

dict_obj = dict(frame[['A','B']].groupby('A').median().sort_values(by='B'))
```

My problem is that I want column A as Key and column B as values but somehow I am getting a weird dictionary

```
dict_obj
{'B': A
 3    2
 2    5
 1    6
 Name: B, dtype: int64}
```

i want dictionary object as

```
{1:6,2:5,3:2}
```

Could someone help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [**`pd.Series.to_dict`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html) method

```
frame.groupby('A').B.median().to_dict()

{'1': 6, '2': 5, '3': 2}
```